# Scroll lag in UITableView cells with large images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I've created a prototype `UITableViewCell` and populated it with dictionaries containing strings with image paths and label text for the cell. I'm using the same image size for the `UITableViewCell`'s `UIImageView` as in lager image views in my app, and some of the images are pretty large.. Like ie 300w x 800h and 300 kb size. So each cell is loading content about 500 kb totally. So when I run the app, on the first scroll down the UITableView (when the cells are created), i experience a lag in the scrolling.

If I leave it like this, will it go through the App Store review or is it likely to be rejected for this? Heard of any cases?

I know I can make some smaller images for UITableViewCell. Then, what is the preferred pixle dimentions for the `UIImageView` (older iphone and retina)? (Or is there maybe a maximun kb loading limit for `UITableViewCell`?)

If you're going to say 44 and 88 points, research is telling me this is the *default height of the* `UITableViewCell` *itself*, and got nothing to do with `UIImageView` dimentions, or kb limit if there is one..

And last: Is there other (apple approved ways) of avoiding the lag? Like creating the cells before the scroll begins, or something?

Comment: please see LazyTableImages sample application (pple.developer  )http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Ps. I suppose the lag is caused by the load of the images, not when searching for the correct dictionary index and string values, as it's only 100 dicts with 10 strings each, stored in a plist loaded to a mutable array in viewdidload..

Comment: Thanks. But I'm only using main bundle for images, uploading them to a server is not the preferred solutin at the moment but maybe a long term solution.

Comment: u r using any background thread to display images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using [LazyLoading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). If the images are coming from Server. That is the main issue of the lag(delay) and Since hte cell is reused So whenever you scroll It loads the image each time.

Also Since you have said that the images are very large So try converting the images to smaller size. **The size of the image is not predefined to 44 or 88 or anything. We can set the size depending upon the height of the cell.**

**EDIT**
As Kristoffer Said that the images are from his main bundle and not from the server
Can you please try changing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the line

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

with

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
```

Not much sure whether it will work or not. But it will stop reusing the cell So Your cell wont reload the already loaded image in the cell.

Comment: @KristofferBilek Please have a look at the Edit

Comment: Thanks for great advices! Will try this and later move on to LazyLoading as I get the server up and going. :-)